# Form always select one option and does not populate the value in other field

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

There is a select field of a form (use to update the existing data) which takes the input option(state) from a database table and based on that value it automatically fills the value of another field(region) using ajax. I am facing two problems with this code.

1. Any option selected on the first field(state) always gives the output value(rid) as '7' whereas different options are having different value.The value(rid) should be corresponding to the option.
2. AJAX send the value 7 by post method and result is corresponding to the value '7' but is not getting filled in the other option(region)

My tblregion is like this

[image: Table Image]

```
<div class="col-md-4 form-group"style="padding-right:0px;" >
<div class="form-group">
<label for="Region" >State</label>

<?php 
$sql="select rid,statename,region from tblregion order by statename";
$stmt=$dbh->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute();
$arrstate=$stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
?>

<select class="form-control" name="state" id="state1" onchange="onStateChange()">
<option value="<?php echo htmlentities($result->rid);?>"><?php echo htmlentities($result->statename);?></option>
<?php
foreach($arrstate as $state){
?>
<option value="<?php echo $state['rid']?>"><?php echo $state['statename']?></option>
<?php
}
?>
</select>
</div></div>

<div class="col-md-2 form-group" style="padding-left:0px;">
<label for="Region" >Region</label>
<select class="form-control" name="Region" id="region" readonly>
<option>Region</option>
</select>
</div>
```

My ajax is working fine. The code for java script is

```
<script>
  function onStateChange() {
   
    var rid = jQuery(state1).val();
    alert(rid);
    jQuery.ajax({
      type: "post",
      url: "get_data.php",
      data: "id=" + rid,
      success: function (result) {
        jQuery('#region').html(result);
        //var oput = 'result';
        alert(result);
        //document.getElementById('region').value =result;
      },
    });
  }
</script>
```

Comment: What is $result in the first option?

Comment: @CodeThing This is a form used to update the records.$result gives the value of existing record from another table.

Comment: But you can just compare that value in the loop and set that particular options as selected if matched.

Comment: Also jQuery(state1).val() should be jQuery('#state1').val()

Comment: @CodeThing I could not get what u mean. This form is used to update the existing record.There is field state and another field region.if user wants to updtae the state field he will select the option in state field and it will automatically populate the region field based on the value.

Comment: @CodeThing I changed as per your advice  still it is giving alert ouput as'7'

Comment: Do inspect elements and observe what options you have in first select dropdown.

Comment: I checked it here all option and corresponding values are available .Inspect element shows that it is sending valure 7 always.

Comment: What you say is happening, can't really be reproduced. _If_ the options actually have the proper values set as you say, there is no reason why this JS code should grab the wrong one - https://jsfiddle.net/4trjyp2w/

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this.

```
<div class="col-md-4 form-group"style="padding-right:0px;" >
<div class="form-group">
<label for="Region" >State</label>

<?php 
$sql="select rid,statename,region from tblregion order by statename";
$stmt=$dbh->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute();
$arrstate=$stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
?>

<select class="form-control" name="state" id="state1" onchange="onStateChange()">
<?php
foreach($arrstate as $state){
?>
<option value="<?php echo $state['rid']?>" <?php echo $result->id == $state['rid'] ? 'selected="selected"' : ''; ?>><?php echo $state['statename']?></option>
<?php
}
?>
</select>
</div></div>

<div class="col-md-2 form-group" style="padding-left:0px;">
<label for="Region" >Region</label>
<select class="form-control" name="Region" id="region" readonly>
<option>Region</option>
</select>
</div>
```

Also you can alert this to get selected option

```
jQuery('#state1 option:selected').val()
```

Comment: No It is not working .Can you send complete code. how will the existing data will populate by this select option

Comment: I wrote this code based on your initial code in the question. It is difficult to judge from the code you have provided. The problem might be somewhere else.

Comment: I guess you need to debug more as to what current options you are having for state dropdown. What is currently selected and what it becomes when you change it.

Comment: I also agree with you but this problem is very strange.Actually This form opens as a bootstrap popup will it affect any behaviour of field